# How to prevent GAE appspot.com address to show up in browser address bar

Tags: jsp, google-app-engine

I mapped my domain to my GAE app which starts with JSP page. As soon user enters domain url in the browser it redirects to the JSP and http://projectID.appspot.com/MyStartPage.jsp appears in the address bar. I don't want users know my project id of that it is hosted at Google Cloud. How I can prevent that?

Comment: One option would be to map your app to a custom domain, which should show instead.

Comment: You need to remove this redirect from your code